# How can I choose an iOS simulator as the destination in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am an iOS noob. I had a project running on the iPhone simulator in Xcode 4.4. To resolve a different issue, I un-installed 4.4 and then installed 4.5.1. Now when I try to run my project on the simulator I get an error "Xcode cannot run using the selected device: No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination."

How do I choose an iOS simulator as the destination?

Where do I click?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There should be a menu in the top left region of the toolbar section of the IDE. It should have a run button, a stop button, and then the name of your app and a label saying IOS Device. Click view-->show toolbar if you don't see it. Click on IOS Device and you should get a drop down menu of devices. The simulator should be in that list.

Answer (score 10):

[image: This should do it]

This should do it, its very simple actually

Answer (score 8):

Just in case anyone finds this helpful --

Sometimes your version of xCode doesn't support the deployment targets.

My iOS simulator did not show up as a destination until I set the deployment target down to 7.0 (it seems like 7.1 may not be supported by xCode 5.0, but only 5.1 [not confirmed]).

Hope that helps if anyone stumbles across it.

Comment: Initially, Xcode only displayed "iOS device" as the sole option in my case.  The deployment target was set to 8.2, but after I changed the deployment target once, I was able to keep the deployment target at 8.2 and have access to all the device options in the select field.  Some sort of bug with Xcode.

Answer (score 4):

For me the problem was that the selection in the toolbar only shows up for a certain width of the XCode window

Comment: I cannot believe this was my problem I spent an hour on!!! Ohhhhh man!  The macbook air on max resolution cannot show the target unless made bigger than the display.  haha, what a joke.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to add devices to the Simulators list by clicking on `Window->Devices` (`Shift+Command+2`), and clicking on the `+` at the bottom left to add Simulators.
After you click on Create, the device(s) will show up

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to set Supported Platforms correctly

[image: XCode showing Supported Platforms]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The simulator would run a different device than chosen in the size field under "Simulated Matrix".

I dug around and found in Xcode's menu: Product/Destination. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFcMp.jpg) I was then able to run the simulator for the correct size.

Hope this helps !!